# Purposely raising exceptions to use catch

Tags: c#, exception-handling

For a typical `if...else` wrapped with exception handling, is something like the following example a recommended practice to avoid code duplication?

```
try
{
    if (GetDataFromServer())
    {
        return ProcessData();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

instead of...

```
try
{
    if (GetDataFromServer())
    {
        return ProcessData();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

I know there is a slight performance hit, but I'm wondering if this is considered to be an acceptable practice. I currently do it the second method - especially in cases where I need to handle specific exceptions differently - but I was wondering if the first method is appropriate for simple cases.

Comment: if the method is small enough I'll just remove the else and return null outside of the trycatch block so I have to return null only once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Using exception handling for flow control is discouraged by Microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms998547.aspx#scalenetchapt05_topic24)

[And a round table on the topic is available.](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/round-table-1-should-exceptions-ever-be-used-for-flow-control--net-30947)

That being said, C# supports doing so, and I suppose it depends on the condition encountered whether an exception is the most appropriate response.

Comment: It strikes me that this sort of thing is just trying real hard to not use events.

Comment: @radarbob: How are events related to this?

Comment: @grovesNL - Throwing an exception at a specific point to call a certain method in a catch block? Quacks like an event to me.

Comment: @radarbob: It's not an event. There are lots of sample use cases where this would be used, as discussed in the answer's roundtable link.

Comment: @radarbob Just a bit of clarification, exceptions were designed as a way of signaling the caller that something has occurred which the called method is unable to handle. However, an event must be listened for. An exception is a forced interruption of the normal flow of a program. An uncaught exception will cause the entire application to abend.

Comment: @radarbob It doesn't look like an event to me, but it does look like a twisted form of goto.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what these resources do and why do you recommend these as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: @gnat The title of the first link explains it perfectly. Microsoft *strongly* discourages using exceptions for flow control. As I had originally posted my answer, the title and it's link were separate. It was subsequently edited to make my sentence the hyperlink.

The second link was an in-depth discussion on the topic, something I felt added additional insight. The poster of the question found the information that I provided quite helpful.

Comment: @gnat what's wrong with my answer anyway? Did I not clearly state my case? I suppose I could have been more verbose, but it wasn't necessary to answer the question. And why should I be dinged for someone else's edits?

Comment: The edict that exceptions shouldn't be used as flow control has always struck me as funny; exceptions are by their very nature a flow control mechanism. Maybe the rule should be "don't use exceptions to perform a *local* transfer of control?"

Answer (score 6):

The performance hit is most probably negligible, as explained in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46960/23788).

So let's go with the idea that performance isn't an issue. You're throwing `System.Exception`, *just to move execution into the `catch` clause*. Throwing a `BadControlFlowThatShouldBeRewrittenException` would probably be overkill though.

Let's break this down. We have:

- Method `GetDataFromServer` (method names should be PascalCase in C#), which can possibly throw an exception, or return a `bool`.
- If result was `true`, run `ProcessData`.
- Return `null` otherwise.

Looks like the method where this code is written, is simply doing too many things. `GetDataFromServer` returning a `bool` looks like a design flaw, I'd be expecting that method to *return the data it's getting from the server*, some `IEnumerable<SomeType>` that would contain 0 or more items - i.e. happy path returns *n* items where *n > 0*, not-so-happy path returns 0 items, and unhappy path blows up with an unhandled exception, whatever that is.

That changes what the method looks like, quite a lot - again it's hard to tell whether this makes sense, because the original post only has one exit point (and thus wouldn't compile, as *not all code paths return a value*), so this is only a wild guess:

```
try
{
    var result = GetDataFromServer();
    return ProcessData(result);
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

Here you'd look at `ProcessData` and see that it's iterating the `result`, and returns `null` if there's no item in the `IEnumerable`.

Now why is the method returning `null`? Server was down? Is there a bug in the query? The connection string is using the wrong credentials? Whenever `GetDataFromServer` blows up with an exception you're not expecting, you're swallowing it, shoving it under the carpet and returning a `null` value. I'd recommend catching specific exceptions in this case, and log everything else; debugging will be much easier that way.

With a general `catch` clause that doesn't capture the exception, it gets pretty hard to diagnose anything. I'd minimally do this instead:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    return null;
}
```

Now you can at least break and inspect `e` if things go wrong.

---

**TL;DR**: No, throwing and catching exceptions for flow control isn't a good idea.

Comment: This answer demonstrates exactly why I tried to keep my code generic: I didn't want to list out every single exception that I actually make in my code; I didn't want to list the actual method names; I didn't want to list the method declaration; I didn't want syntax suggestions. I had a single question about whether throwing exceptions for flow control was okay, which was promptly answered by B2K. I would be happy to debate this on meta.

Comment: sounds like this should have been a question for Programmers then.  we review code, not ideas.

Answer (score 2):

in your first answer there is a performance hit that doesn't need to be there.

```
try
{
    if (GetDataFromServer())
    {
        return ProcessData();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

when you exit the if statement to enter into the Catch statement when you don't have to makes the code switch directions, so to say.

if you want to `return null;`  do it in the else statement not in a catch that is caught after being thrown from the else statement.

Probably doesn't apply to your **Real** code, but for the Generic code that you gave it does apply.

Standards say you shouldn't do this.

Standards say you should do it like this, (again based on Generic Code Given in OP)

```
if (GetDataFromServer())
{
    return ProcessData();
}
else
{
    Return null
}
```

and since you don't have any specific exceptions that you are catching you shouldn't even have a try catch here.

you want to see Exceptions when they occur so that you can fix the issue that creates the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Why not the far simpler:

```
if (!GetDataFromServer()) return null;
ProcessData();
```

If an exception handler is going to exist it should be in ProcessData()

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to pass exceptions through `ProcessData()` to the uppermost level?

Comment: @grovesNL Nothing useful was being done with the exception here.

Comment: How so? If `ProcessData()` throws an exception now it's not handled. I want it to `return null` at this level if `ProcessData()` throws an exception, without modifying `ProcessData()` itself.